# How to show logo on top center when viewed on smaller devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a logo inside header menu bar. The logo appears on top left corner of the header. When I viewed on smaller devices logo is hidden inside hamburger menu. Is there a way when viewed on smaller devices we can show logo on top center, if viewed on larger devices same as it is, which means top left corner

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <div class="navbar-logo">
                    <img src="Images/Logo.jpg" ui-sref="homeIndex" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Virginia System of Care" height="60" width="140" />
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a ui-sref="homeIndex">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: so you need to center your logo in smaller devices ?

Comment: yes when I viewed on mobile devices my logo is inside hamburger menu, instead when i viewed on smaller devices I want logo to be placed on top center

Comment: wait, let me do it, because i dont try in bootstrap 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i change place of your image, so it cant be hide in small resolution and for center logo  in small resolution i added some CSS that apply only in small resolution

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <img src="" class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="homeIndex" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Virginia System of Care" height="60" width="140">
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="homeIndex">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```